# Import another property file from alfresco-global.properties?

Tags: alfresco

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com)'s properties can be set in [alfresco-global.properties](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_Configuration#alfresco-global.properties_.28V3.2.2B.29).

I have a cluster with 5 nodes, and whenever I have to change a setting (=several times per day), I need to go modify on each of the 5 nodes.

I would like to only modify a single file, on a shared NFS drive. I have thought of making alfresco-global.properties a symlink to `/nfs/nico/alfresco-global.properties` but unfortunately each node has a different `alfresco.jgroups.bind_address`.

I would like to split the configuration in two files: a CONF1 file specific to each cluster node, and a common CONF2 file, shared over NFS.

QUESTION: how can I "import" CONF2 from CONF1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "import" mechanism in properties files. To solve your problem you really need to externalize the node specific properties from the cluster wide ones. The strategy you envisioned of accessing the same file from all app servers through a network attached FS is the easiest solution. If you look at `core-services-context.xml` you'll find the following:

```
<!-- Global properties used in property expansion throughout the container, overridable via JNDI or System properties -->
<bean id="global-properties" class="org.alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:alfresco/repository.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:alfresco/domain/transaction.properties</value>
            <!-- <value>classpath:alfresco/jndi.properties</value> -->
            <!--  Overrides supplied by modules -->
            <value>classpath*:alfresco/module/*/alfresco-global.properties</value>
            <!--  Installer or user-provided defaults -->
            <value>classpath*:alfresco-global.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
    [...]
</bean>
```

You can either declare a new `JndiPropertiesFactoryBean` in a custom Spring context which loads a properties file from a convenient, shared location, or you can exploit the modules properties loading mechanism and make sure you have `alfresco/module/cluster-defaults/alfresco-global.properties` in your classpath pointing to such a shared location.